# Icono grande en storyboard (xcode 10)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Acabo de actualizar mi Xcode a 10.0, de pronto todas los iconos de UIImageView y UIButton toma la más grande (2x).
¿Cómo puedo hacer para volver a ver una vista previa "REAL" al diseñar en el storyboard?

En el Storyboard:

[image: En el storyboard]

En el emulador:

[image: En el emulador]

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

esto sucede cuando exportas las imágenes mal dimensionandas, hay elementos como los botones que necesitan el tamaño específico que vas a usar, te recomiendo verificar el tamaño de las imágenes y exportarlas en menor tamaño, es decir si actualmente tus imágenes son 
1x = 30px
2x = 60px 
3x = 90px

reduce su tamaño a algo así como 
1x = 22px
2x = 44px 
3x = 66px

Te dijo la guía de los tamaños que debes usar [aquí](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)

Evitar en los botones usar imágenes en formato vectorial PDF.